# Flink async stream processing exception handling for replaying message sometime in future

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

### We are developing a stream processing service which coming from Kinesis to Flink.

- The service will need to calling several external APIs to enrich data stream so Async/IO API will be used in our case.
- In case of any exception, we would like to capture the events to a sink and selectively replaying the messages to Flink for retrying.
- We have control of Kinesis, Kinesis allows replaying message up to 7 days with extended data retention but not selectively and we wish to keep for longer

we are thinking about side outputs the exception stream and save to separate sink. Is there a mechanism to pulling data from sink to Kinesis with minimum manual effort? we have not decided about what sink we would use. Is there a better solution or recommendation?

Comment: Do You have any specific number of retrials or time to wait between retries in mind ?

Comment: We would like to keep at least one month of failed events, and replay them selectively base on error type anytime within the month.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a good use case for the exception stream. I think Flink does have `FlinkKinesisProducer` which pulls data from Flink to Kinesis.

Comment: @RyanYan Did you get any solution for your problem?